# How resolution methods' rules apply in proofs

Tags: logic

I understand that resolution methods are used to prove something by disproving its negation (proof by contradiction), but I don't understand how this idea is implemented in formulas.

The following is a set of problems that was given to me as an assignment, and even after I got the complete answers for those problems in its review session I still don't understand how it works.

```
Problem 1                                   

Premises:                                   
P Ʌ Q  → R                                  
R Ʌ T → S                                   
→ P                                 
→ Q                                 
→ T                                 
Conclusion:  S  drives from the premises    Therefore: demonstrate       S →    through resolution      

R Ʌ T → S       S  →                            
    R /\ T ->         P /\ Q -> R                               
        T /\ P /\ Q ->           -> T                           
            P /\ Q ->                 -> P                      
                Q ->                      -> Q                  
                    ->
```

Why is there nothing on the left side of the arrows of the premises? 
(-> P, ->Q, -> T)

Why does

```
R /\ T
```

lead to

```
P /\ Q -> R
```

?

And I'm wondering about basically the same thing on the rest of the problems (2-4)

```
Problem 2                                   
Premises:                                   
P Ʌ Q Ʌ R → S                                   
U Ʌ V → P                                   
W → Q                                   
→ R                                 
→ U                                 
→ V                                 
→ W                                 

Conclusion:  S  drives from the premises    Therefore: demonstrate       S →    through resolution          

P /\ Q /\ R -> S          S ->                                  
    P /\ Q /\ R ->            U /\ V -> P                               
        Q /\ /\ U /\ V ->                W -> Q                         
            R /\ U /\ V /\ W ->                -> R                     
                U /\ V /\ W ->                     -> U                 
                    V /\ W  ->                         -> V             
                        W ->                               -> W         
                            ->  



Problem 3                                                                           
Premises:                                       
P(x) → Q(x)                                     
Q(x) → R(x)                                     
S(x) Ʌ T(y) → P(x)                                      
→ S(1)                                      
→ S(2)                                      
→ S(3)                                      
→ T(1)                                      
→ T(3)                                      

Conclusion:  R(2)  derives from the premises.   Therefore:  demonstrate  R(2) →     through resolution          

Q(x0) → R(x0)            R(2) →                             
        {<x0,2>}                                
P(x1) → Q(x1)           Q(2) →                          
        {<x1, 2>}                               
    P(2) ->     S(x2) /\ T(y2) -> P(x2)                         
        {<x, 2>}                                
        S(2) /\ T (y) ->        -> S(2)                     
            T(y) ->         -> T(1)                 
                {<y2, 1>}                       
                ->
```

What is going on in the curly braces, like

```
{<x0,2>}
```

?

```
Problem 4                               

Demonstrate by using resolution method that Anna has a grandmother                              

→   Mother(Lena,Ida)                            
→   Mother(Ida,Anna)                            

Mother(x,y) Ʌ Mother(y,z) → Grandmother(x,z)                                

Mother(x0,y0) Ʌ Mother(y0,z0) → Grandmother(x0,z0)      Grandmother(x,Anna) →           
                {x0,x>,<z0,Anna>}               
Motherr(x,y0) Ʌ Motherr(y0,Anna) →              -> Mother(Lena, Ida)                
            {<x, Lena>,<y0, Ida>}                   
    Mother(Ida, Anna) ->            -> Mother(Ida, Anna)                
            ->
```

Comment: "I don't understand how this idea is implemented in formulas." What textbook are you using ? Lectures notes ? For sure there must be examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is there nothing on the left side of the arrows of the premises? (-> P, ->Q, -> T)

That "nothing" implies them means $P, Q,$ and $T$ are each *unconditionally* true.

Conversely, $R\land T$ implies "nothing" means $R\land T$ is false.

> Why does $R \land T$ lead to $P \land Q \to R$

It doesn't.  $R\land T\to\{\}$ *and* $P\land Q \to R$ combine to derive $P\land Q\land T\to\{\}$. The resolution process cancels the $R$ on the left and right and combines the remainder of the statements. $$\dfrac{\require{cancel}\cancel R\land T\to\{\}\qquad P\land Q\to\cancel R}{P\land Q\land T\to \{\}}$$

In full...

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{R \land T \to S  \qquad S \to\varnothing}{R \land T \to\varnothing}\quad\lower{1.5ex}{P \land Q \to R}}{T \land P \land Q \to\varnothing}\quad\lower{1.5ex}{\varnothing\to T}}{ P \land Q \to\varnothing}\quad\lower{1.5ex}{\varnothing\to P}}{Q \to\varnothing}\quad\lower{1.5ex}{\varnothing\to Q}}{\varnothing\to\varnothing}$$

> What is going on in the curly braces, like $\{\langle x_0,2\rangle\}$

They merely indicate that the free variable and constant term were being resolved in that step; ie, "all instances of $x_0$ are replaced by $2$".$$\dfrac{Q(x_0)\to R(x_0)\qquad R(2)\to\{\}}{Q(2)\to\{\}}{\{\langle x_0,2\rangle\}}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you tell me how you read the formula in English as well? For example, how does "R∧T→∅      P∧Q→R" read? Is it "If R and T implies nothing, then P and Q implies R"? Also, what is the purpose of replacing x0 with a number like 2? And why is it x0 instead of just a regular x?